# Creating Elastic Beanstalk environment with specified VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-cli

I'm trying to create an Elastic Beanstalk environment using the AWS CLI

```
aws elasticbeanstalk create-environment \
    --application-name my-application \
    --environment-name my-environment \
    --region us-east-1 \
    --solution-stack-name "64bit Amazon Linux 2015.09 v2.0.6 running Docker 1.7.1" \
    --version-label my-version
```

but this dumps everything into the default VPC, whereas I'd like to put it in a specific (non-default) VPC. I know this can be accomplished through the AWS web interface. Can it be accomplished with the CLI? Choosing a VPC is not mentioned in the [create-environment docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/elasticbeanstalk/create-environment.html).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Elastic Beanstalk has it's own CLI implementation that is much more robust than the one integrated into the AWS CLI. You can read more about it and download it [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb3-create.html). Then, you can use the eb cli as follows to specify the VPC:

```
eb create \
    --elb-type application \
    --region us-east-1 \
    --platform "64bit Amazon Linux 2015.09 v2.0.6 running Docker 1.7.1" \
    --version my-version \
    --vpc.id <vpc to launch into> \
    my-environment-name
```