# How do I define an existing custom VPC when creating an Elastic Beanstalk Environment from Command Line?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I need to build an Elastic Beanstalk Environment that is configured to use a VPC I have already defined in my AWS Console.  I am using the AWS Elastic Beanstalk CLI setup to do this:
https://github.com/aws/aws-elastic-beanstalk-cli-setup

I found this github project after searching for how to define the VPC settings in the Elastic Beanstalk CLI:
https://github.com/awsdocs/elastic-beanstalk-samples/tree/master/configuration-files/aws-provided/environment-configuration

On my workstation (laptop) where Elastic Beanstalk Environment CLI is installed I have the following working directory:

```
example@ubuntu:~/Documents/eb_test$ ls -la
..
.ebextensions
.elasticbeanstalk
.gitignore
platform.yaml
tomcat_platform.json
example@ubuntu:~/Documents/eb_test$ cd .ebextensions
example@ubuntu:~/Documents/eb_test/.ebextensions$ ls -la
..
vpc-custom-loadbalanced.config
example@ubuntu:~/Documents/eb_test/.ebextensions$ cat vpc-custom-loadbalanced.config

option_settings:
  aws:ec2:vpc:
    VPCId: "vpc-00000000"
    Subnets: "subnet-00000000,subnet-00000000"
    ELBSubnets: "subnet-00000000,subnet-00000000"
example@ubuntu:~/Documents/eb_test/.ebextensions$ cd ..
example@ubuntu:~/Documents/eb_test$ eb platform create
```

Even though the VPC is spelled correctly and defined on my AWS account (other services are currently using it) The Elastic Beanstalk instance uses the default VPC configuration on my AWS account instead.

Following this answer:
[Creating Elastic Beanstalk environment with specified VPC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46308134/creating-elastic-beanstalk-environment-with-specified-vpc)
I have also tried this command instead:

```
example@ubuntu:~/Documents/eb_test$ eb platform create \
                                        --vpc.id vpc-00000000 \
                                        --Subnets "subnet-00000000,subnet-00000001"
```

And gotten this as a response:

```
2020-03-09 20:59:58    ERROR   Failed to create the Packer builder environment: Configuration validation exception: Invalid option value: 'null' (Namespace: 'aws:ec2:vpc', OptionName: 'Subnets'): Specify the subnets for the VPC..
```

Is there a way to run this command and successfully set a custom VPC with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try creating with vpc id and subnet ids. Check out the complete `eb create` options here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb3-create.html

```
eb create --vpc.id vpc-id1 --vpc.dbsubnets subnet-id1,subnet-id2 --vpc.ec2subnets subnet-id1,subnet-id2
```